# how to implement adjusted cosine similarity in php?

Tags: php, cosine-similarity

I'm little confused when I trying to implement the adjusted cosine algorithm in PHP, so before I ask the question, here is my table.

> manual rating table

```
==========================================================
|       | Item A    | Item B    | Item C    | Average    |
==========================================================
|User 1 | -         | 5         | 4         | 4.5        |
|User 2 | 4         | -         | 3         | 3.5        |
|User 3 | 2         | 2         | 2         | 3          |
==========================================================
```

> rating table in database

```
=====================================
| id | userid | item_id    | rating |
=====================================
| 1  |   1    |     B      |   5    |
| 2  |   1    |     C      |   4    |
| 3  |   2    |     A      |   4    |
| 4  |   2    |     C      |   3    |
| 5  |   3    |     A      |   2    |
| 5  |   3    |     B      |   2    |
| 6  |   3    |     C      |   2    |
=====================================
```

and then, I have a manual calculation that I want to change into PHP code.

[image: the image].

Then my question, how to implement that calculation in PHP code?

Comment: You extract the values using SQL queries, and calculate the result with the equation you posted.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php, http://php.net/manual/en/ref.math.php, http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: what's the difference between `cos()`, and adjusted cosine.  I'll admit I slept during math class ( a lot )  http://php.net/manual/en/function.cos.php

Comment: Also MySql has a decent set of math stuff too. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html  I've seen stuff like Haversine implemented right in a query, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula